# Open file from QGIS and search for text within it

Tags: qgis, actions

I have a lot of data associated with a layer in QGIS. Each individual feature has its own information associated with it - but this information is within a number of different PDF files.

I have managed to create an action that opens the particular PDF file associated with the element easy enough - but I want to be able to search within the PDF once it is open. For example:

open [% "File Link"%]
searchtext = [% "ID" %]

So, I want to open a pdf file from one column (in the attributes table), and then search that pdf with the word in another column of the attributes table.

Essentially, I want the action to "Ctrl F" and jump to the correct page without me having to manually do it.

Alternatively, if I extracted all the PDF's - is there a way to search a folder with the [% "ID" %] name, so I don't have to link every single document path to its corresponding feature?

Comment: There are python libraries for reading PDFs, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python. Dont know how to do it in QGIS though